# Styling reCAPTCHA background color

Tags: css, recaptcha

A few months ago, I started using Google's reCAPTCHA 2.0, which fit my website design okay, but now it suddenly started including a white background on the right and bottom sides.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/70wq55y2/.

The culprit style is:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Unfortunately, since it's within an iframe, I can't reach it, but I was wondering if there are any other "hacks" I could try, 'cause this looks really ugly on my website now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pretty hack-y, but you can change the size of the iframe to remove the extra white space  and then round it to match the rounded borders of the captcha

`iframe {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 302px;
    height: 76px;
 }`

That's all I can think of. reCAPTCHA also has a dark theme according to the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) but sadly it doesn't remove the white background :(

Comment: That's what I use too, event though its pretty ugly :(
You can add it only to the recaptcha iframe using child selectors or javascript. An ugly example from an old site i developed:
    .g-recaptcha > div > div > iframe {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 75px;
 }

Comment: That's better than putting up with the uneven background. Thanks!